# How to establish connection between Nifi and SQL server using JDBC driver?

Tags: sql-server, apache-nifi, mssql-jdbc

I am running Nifi on windows machine and would like to establish a connection to the MS SQL Server on the same machine.
I downloaded the JDBC driver from Microsoft and put mssql-jdbc-11.2.1.jre11.jar to the lib folder of Nifi. Below is the properties for Controller Service Detail in Nifi to connect to the Sql server.
**Database Connection URL:** jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;databaseName=test_database;encrypt=true;user=nifireader;password=***;
**Database Driver Class Name:** com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
[image]

I also created a user inside Sql Server and gave it a read access to use it for Nifi. But I get the SSL error and could not solve it so far. Is there any other steps that I need to take to establish a connection?

```
2022-12-09 17:47:05,052 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL ExecuteSQL[id=f76ca380-0184-1000-3a89-b878a90723ed] Unable to execute SQL select query SELECT * FROM tbl_tags due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:7fcd7f53-9532-44da-96ce-56eac78049f6). No FlowFile to route to failure
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:7fcd7f53-9532-44da-96ce-56eac78049f6)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.AbstractDBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(AbstractDBCPConnectionPool.java:573)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.AbstractDBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(AbstractDBCPConnectionPool.java:550)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:55)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:254)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:105)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractExecuteSQL.onTrigger(AbstractExecuteSQL.java:255)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1356)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:246)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:102)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:7fcd7f53-9532-44da-96ce-56eac78049f6)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:653)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:531)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.AbstractDBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(AbstractDBCPConnectionPool.java:560)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:7fcd7f53-9532-44da-96ce-56eac78049f6
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3806)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1906)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3329)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2950)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2790)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1663)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1064)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:374)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:649)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1382)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1295)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:416)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:388)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1795)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:110)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.HostNameOverrideX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(SQLServerTrustManager.java:86)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1510)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You are telling it to connect with encryption (i.e.: TLS) but not telling it how it should handle SQL Server's SSL/TLS certificate. Does the instance have an SSL/TLS certificate issued by a public CA (Certificate Authority), or one from your own organization's CA, or is it still using the self-signed certificate that gets installed by default? Have a read through [Connecting with encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read the info on the link you shared and corrected the connection url by setting trustServerCertificate=true. It works now.